# How to determine with which dotnet sdk an assembly is built

Tags: .net, build, dotnet-sdk

***Is there a way in which I can determine with which dotnet SDK an assembly (targetting dotnet core) is built?***

Up till now we didn't use a global.json to specify with which dotnet SDK to build our assemblies, meaning the latest SDK is used.
We have recently switched to dotnet 3.1.x for new projects but still have a lot of projects that are targetting dotnet 2.1.x

*I'm not sure what kind of subtle changes (or even bugs?) could be introduced when building a project targetting dotnet 2.1.x with dotnet 3.1.x SDK*

To be sure we are going to use [global.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json?tabs=netcore3x) (in orde to define which .NET Core SDK version is used when building). And, if possible, are going to check how many assemblies were already shipped that were build with a higher dotnet core SDK. Is it even possible?

Comment: It is possible to view the target framework of the DLL using the `ildasm` tool. If you use the tool to view the metainfo, you will see it as an assembly attribute. I didn't have time to to work out the exact command line solution to automate this.

Comment: thanks @virusstorm , however I'm not looking for the target dotnet core version of an assembly but rather the dotnet SDK that was used to build the assembly

Answer (score 2):

Note: there may be a simpler way of doing this, but I don't know it at the moment. I don't know of any way of determining it from an *existing* assembly.

When you build with the .NET Core SDK, a `NETCoreSdkVersion` MSBuild property is set.

You could create a target with `BeforeTargets="CoreCompile"` that generates source code including that build property, to add an assembly-level attribute (that you'd have to define yourself). This would be similar to how `AssemblyInfo.g.cs` is generated already.

I'm afraid I don't have enough time to put together a complete example of it right now - but you can see an example of automated code generation [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-dotnet/blob/master/src/Google.Cloud.Functions.Invoker/targets/Google.Cloud.Functions.Invoker.targets). That's part of a `targets` directory in a NuGet package, so that code depending on that package gets the code generation automatically; you could do something like that, or if everything is in the same solution you could use a `Directory.Build.targets` or similar.

Comment: Pefect ! Thanks. We already add a lot of additional information to the AssemblyConfiguration attribute. This NETCoreSdkVersion is a perfect addition to that.